# Can't add nuget package to Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Package FM.IceLink.WebRTC 2.3.11 is not compatible with netstandard1.4 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.4). Package FM.IceLink.WebRTC 2.3.11 supports:
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.1.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.Win32.Primitives 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.AppContext 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Collections 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Collections.Concurrent 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Console 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Diagnostics.Debug 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Diagnostics.Tracing 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Globalization 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Globalization.Calendars 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.IO 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.IO.Compression 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.IO.Compression.ZipFile 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Linq 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Linq.Expressions 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Net.Http 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Net.Primitives 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.ObjectModel 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Reflection 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Reflection.Extensions 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Reflection.Primitives 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Resources.ResourceManager 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime.Extensions 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime.Handles 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime.InteropServices 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime.Numerics 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Text.Encoding 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Text.Encoding.Extensions 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Text.RegularExpressions 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Threading 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Threading.Tasks 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Threading.Timer 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Xml.XDocument 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.ComponentModel.Primitives 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for FM.IceLink 2.2.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Package FM.IceLink 2.2.0 is not compatible with netstandard1.4 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.4). Package FM.IceLink 2.2.0 supports:
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
Checking compatibility for FM 2.0.0.5 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Package FM 2.0.0.5 is not compatible with netstandard1.4 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.4). Package FM 2.0.0.5 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 1.1.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for runtime.native.System 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for runtime.native.System.IO.Compression 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Buffers 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for System.ComponentModel 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for runtime.fedora.23-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for runtime.fedora.24-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for runtime.opensuse.13.2-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for runtime.opensuse.42.1-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for runtime.osx.10.10-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for runtime.rhel.7-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for runtime.ubuntu.14.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Checking compatibility for runtime.ubuntu.16.10-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add this package to a .NET Standard library because it only targets .net35, .net40, .net45 all full framework and Windows Phone 8.

You will have to get the source and retarget it or ask the author to provide .NET Standard variants.